# JavaScript for output 6 random numbers

Tags: javascript

I'd like my output has 6 random numbers but my code only displays 4 numbers, and the numbers are the same.

```
var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*41);

for(var i=0; i<7; i++){
    document.write(x + "</br>");
    i++;
}
```

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move `.random()` inside your loop. Also, remove `i++` from your loop, because that is already done by `for()`.

**Demo:** <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

#### Script:

```js
for( var i=0; i<6; i++ ){
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*41);
    document.write(x + "</br>");
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer| one more question, how to sort them in order? `.sort`

Comment: @olo Yeah, `Array.sort()`. Create the random numbers in an array, sort them when done, and then display them.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the i++ inside the form, it's 6 not 7 and you need to calculate the random numbers inside the for loop.

```
for(var i=0; i<6; i++){
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*41);
    document.write(x + "</br>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you incrementing `i` twice? Also, if all the numbers are going to be random, you need to execute the Math function inside of the loop.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    document.write(Math.floor(Math.random()*41) + "<br>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to increment your counter twice.  Also, the random() needs to be inside your loop.

```
var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*41);

for(var i=0; i<6; i++){
    document.write(x + "</br>");
    x = Math.floor(Math.random()*41);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are assigning the var x with a random number before starting the loop, it remains same throughout the execution

try placing it inside the loop,also about incrementing the i, you are doing it in the for loop already so you do not need to do it inside the loop

```
var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*41);//place it inside the loop

for(var i=0; i<7; i++){
    document.write(x + "</br>");
    i++;//remove this
}
```